# Firebase cloud functions routing

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to process paths like */user/:id* and */user/:id/report* in HTTP Trigger Firebase cloud functions with access to param **id ?**

I didn't like next solution because all my functions would be part of the one with prefix **/api** :

```
const app = require('express')();
exports.api= functions.https.onRequest(app);
app.get('/user/:uid/report', (req, res) => {}):
```

But i need something like that:

```
exports['/user/:uid/report'] = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   // ...
});
```

**UPDATE**:
It's impossible to have wildcards in hosting routes and get params from it

Answer (score 6):

You can use Firebase Hosting on top of Cloud Functions for Firebase to rewrite URLs to suit the path you want.  This means you'll have to `firebase init` again and add Hosting if it's not already.

In your project `firebase.json` you'll have to add a [function rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function) to send all requests to hosting `/**` to function `api`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "function": "api"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When you deploy, you'll be given a hosting URL in the output.  Use this instead of your function URL.

And now, with Hosting in front of Functions, you have to ability to set up [caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#managing_cache_behavior).

Comment: I don't think this is good solution, because at the end i will have only one function on cloud to configure timeout and memory, right?

Comment: That's correct.  But you can't have wildcards in hosting rewrites, so you can't redirect a wildcarded path to a regular https function.  This is all we have today.  Feel free to put in a feature request describing your situation: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 4):

You can use your hosting rewrite to map URL to functions like this

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/user/*/report",
    "function": "myFunction"
  }
]
```

But you'll have to process the URL your self to extract each parameter

Comment: My answer works, you can have wildcards in the URL check the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites.

Comment: Sorry for my rude answer before, according to the documentation the URL are glob notation so you can add * in it. here is an example of my api implemented in firebase cloud funcitons https://jsfiddle.net/1x4crn9t/

Answer (score 1):

I would export a function for every resource.

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/:userid/report', reportGenerator);

// Edit: using router directyly didn't worked for me
// you can also define your routes in the express app object
const app = express();
app.use(router);
exports.user = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```